# Is there any concept of democracy in Islam?

Tags: politics

As we know that Islam is a complete quote of life. I heard that there is no concept of democracy in Islam. Is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Islam there be concept of Khilafat. The only authority who can make laws is Allah, and the Khalifah is only there as custodian to enforce those laws. People must submit to these laws whether they like them or not.

In democracy laws are made by the vote of the majority of people or their representatives, whatever the majority agrees upon is declared correct and what it disapproves of is made illegal.

The majority is not always upright, it is the opposite:

> And **if you obey most of those on earth, they will mislead you far away
>   from Allah's Path.** They follow nothing but conjectures, and they do
>   nothing but lie. ([Surat Al-An'am 116](https://legacy.quran.com/6/116))
>
> And so judge (you O Muhammad SAW) between them by what Allah has
>   revealed and follow not their vain desires, but beware of them lest
>   they turn you (O Muhammad SAW) far away from some of that which Allah
>   has sent down to you. And if they turn away, then know that Allah's
>   Will is to punish them for some sins of theirs. **And truly, most of men
>   are Fasiqun (rebellious and disobedient to Allah)**. ([Surat Al-Ma'idah
>   49](https://legacy.quran.com/5/49))

Comment: But Khilafat is based on the votes of the Shura, it's still democracy but in a selected few people.

Answer (score 1):

According to Khilafah-e-Rashidun's tradition -

1. there would be a leader called the Caliph.
   a. the Caliph would be both the head of the state and the religious leader.
2. there would be a committee of elders or wise men, called ["Shura"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shura).
   a. The Caliph would seek their advice on any matter he likes.
   b. if the Caliph passes on, this committee would be responsible for selecting or electing a new Caliph.
3. There would be a chief justice called the ["Qadi"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qadi).
   a. His jurisdiction would be independent of the Caliph. I.e., the Caliph cannot interfere in court matters.
4. There would be a government fund or ["Bayt al-Maal"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayt_al-mal).
   a. The Caliph would be accountable to the "Majlish-e-Shura" regarding the spending of this fund.

The issue with this system was that there was no clear guideline about the membership of the Shura. As a result, after the Rashidun period, the Caliphate plunged into chaos. During the later periods, Shura membership mostly came through succession.

After the Rashidun caliphs, from the Umaiyads to the Ottomans, the basic structure remained the same, except the descendents of the Caliphs became the next Caliphs. This effectively made them kings and their jurisdiction a kingdom. Also, no matter what their characteristics were, they were regarded as religious leaders.

Therefore, the answer to the question is that Islam neither confirms democracy nor denies it.

---

Hey, DVers! Care to explain why my answer was downvoted?

Comment: Great answer, I don't see why this is downvoted. Although this is surely accurate as per historical facts, It would be really helpful if you can provide some references to it if possible.

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan, Plz point out the section you need ref for.

Comment: Tbh, I don't, but the downvoter probably does (for all the points mentioned).

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan, I added Wikipedia links.

Comment: Great, Jazak Allah khair for your answer.